# Start date is delayed by more than three months from Application date in UK

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, working-visas, skilled-migration

I have applied for Skilled Worker Visa in the UK on June 9. However due to delay in processing visa applications by UKVI. my visa is not issued yet. The employer added a note to the CoS stating a new start date (September 19) as you can see, this goes beyond the three months period a worker is allowed to apply before start date of the job.

Does anyone has similar experience please or can advise in some way. My question would be is it okay now that the start date is more than 3 months from my application submission date? and this is due to delay from UKVI not from me.

Many thanks in Advance for all you help and support.

Regards

Comment: What did the employer say when you asked them?

Comment: They are looking into it. But I would appreciate advise from someone who s been in similar situation or can point me to some guidance.